# Unmarshal partial Data bytes into Custom Struct

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have data in the form of `map[string][]byte`, where key is the json field tag of that struct and the value is the byte slice.

Consider this example:

```
type Tweet struct {
    UserId int `json:"user_id"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}
```

```
data = {
"user_id":<some bytes>,
"message":<some bytes>
}
```

`var t Tweet`

How can i unmarshal the corresponding field data into the Tweet struct which can contain any type of field i.e. slice/map/Custom type/pointer type? Do i have to individually map the data of every field one by one or is there any generic way also?

I tried Marshalling the whole data and the unmarshalling back to the struct type but it seems it modifies the actual data internally and it doesn't work.

```
bytes, err := json.Marshal(data)
var t Tweet
err = json.Unmarshal(bytes,&t)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it modifies the actual data internally and it doesn't work"? A marshaling round-trip should work and is what I would do: https://go.dev/play/p/phzE2x-DsYW

Comment: I missed that you start with map[string][]byte, not map[string]any. How are the bytes encoded? If it's already the JSON representation, convert to a map[string]json.RawMessage first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't mentioned about your error, but below is worked for me. You can try like this.

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Tweet struct {
    UserId  int    `json:"user_id"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    // Example data: map of field tags to JSON-encoded byte slices
    data := map[string]json.RawMessage{
        "user_id": []byte(`123`),             // Encoded as a JSON number
        "message": []byte(`"Hello, world!"`), // Encoded as a JSON string
    }

    // Convert map to JSON
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling map to JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    // Unmarshal JSON into Tweet struct
    var t Tweet
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &t); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    // Output the result
    fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled: %+v\n", t)

    // Marshal the Tweet struct back into JSON
    marshalledData, err := json.Marshal(t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling Tweet struct to JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    // Output the marshalled JSON
    fmt.Printf("Marshalled: %s\n", marshalledData)
}
```